# longtable appears before tables

Tags: tables, longtable

I have 7 tables in my paper. The last one is longtable. But in pdf table 7 appears as the first table: the order shown in pdf is: 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.
Numbering the tables is correct but table 7 occurs (appears) as first table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`longtable` does not float, put `\clearpage` immediately before it to stop floats going past.

Comment: Thank you very much David. It works.