# Tables number ordering problem

Tags: tables, longtable, overleaf, sidewaystable

I am using a *{sidewaystable}* and *{longtable}* on a paper. Sidewaystable is **table 2** and longtable is **table3**. Table 2 should be before table 3, but in my paper table 2 is on page 13, and table 3 is on page 11. Therefore, I got a revision on this but I do not know how to fix it. Any help?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494619/113546

Comment: Thanks! This worked but now there is a nice amount of empty space before the table 2. I hope they don't mind about it.

Comment: Is exchanging the order of the `longtable` and `sidewaystable` an option for you?

Comment: you do not have to have space, move the sidewys table later after the longtable so it becomes 3, or move some text from after the longtable to be for it, to fill the space. (ie float the longtable "by hand"

Comment: Check if `\usepackage{placeins}` and then a `\FloatBarrier` before the `longtable` may give a better result.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum it didn't work. Mico, no I cannot change their position. I guess I will leave it as blank